# compare element's of two arrays which are in another array

Tags: javascript

Checking first 2 elements:

[image: checking first 2 element]

Checking next 2 elements:

[image: checking next 2 element]

I have this array, need to compare each 2 elements

```
var my_arr = [
           [0,1,2],
           [0,2,1],
           [1,0,2],
           [1,2,0],
           [2,0,1],
           [2,1,0]
         ];
```

I need to get this as final result. Script must compare every 2 elements of every array and get only one of them

```
var new_arr = [
           [0,1,2],
           [0,2,1],
         ];
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: What is the logic for the result? What information do you want to get from comparing two elements? You haven't actually explained the problem or provided any information that would enable us to help you. Please read [ask].

Comment: there are picture watch it and you can understand the logic

Comment: No, not really. What is the significants of the highlights in the picture?

Comment: there are 6 arrays in one,so if any of two elemets in array are the same in ather arrays don't get them

Comment: *"if any of two elemets in array are the same in ather arrays"* What does that mean? All of these arrays contain the same elements in different order.

Comment: they must be side by side

Comment: I'm added 2-nd picture

Comment: @FelixKling I think the OP wants to check every two sequential members of the array. And then if any array after it has one of those pairs it's eliminated.  So the first array has the pairs 0,1 and 1,2. The second array has 0,2 and 2,1.  Every subsequent array has one of those 4 pairs so they are eliminated.

Comment: @ConradFrix: That makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @ConradFrix: You understad it

Comment: Have anyone ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested approach with iterating the pattern part with `i` and `j` and the part for test with `k` and `l`. If two elements are found the array is spliced.

```js
var array = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]],
    i = 0, j, k, l;

while (i < array.length) {
    j = 0;
    while (j + 1 < array[i].length) {
        k = i + 1;
        test: while (k < array.length) {
            l = 0;
            while (l + 1 < array[k].length) {
                if (array[i][j] === array[k][l] && array[i][j + 1] === array[k][l + 1]) {
                    array.splice(k, 1);
                    continue test;
                }
                l++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```